# Can i copy a game from my friend ps4 to mine without download it from my account?

Tags: ps4

I purchased a game from the ps store from my account, the size of download is 118 gb, my friend has the game downloaded, can i copy the game from his ps4 to mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The PS4 allows you to MOVE game files from your internal hard drive to an external drive (but apparently not the other way around). Note that I say MOVE, not copy. One of you will need to download the game again if you take this route. The hard drive also needs to be formatted using the PS4 readable format, so you won't easily be able to use a PC to make a copy of the hard drive to work around this. You might be able to with a block-level tool, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

If you want to do this, https://blog.playstation.com/archive/2017/03/10/how-to-download-and-store-ps4-games-and-apps-to-an-external-hdd/ explains the process of preparing a HDD for PS4 storage and moving game files. Essentially, go to the applications list in your System Storage settings menu, then press the option button, select "move to extended storage", then select the games and copy them. Then you can play these games from your PS4.

Comment: No dude, i don't mean to copy the game to a hard drive, in the past i get 2 battlefield cds, i download the update and copy it to my friend ps4, from setting ( copy data to another ps4) and it worked, but now i want to copy a game that i purchased it from the store(not cd), i want to know if i copy it i can open it from my account, because u know if i use this methode the ps4 will be formated before copy